# What is the meaning of square bracket in html?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am working in a project of codeigniter. There are some html file located in themes folder and i see some new things.

Can anyone please tell me what is the meaning of this:

```
href="[conf.site_url]/admin/team"

class="[vars.css_menu_team;noerr]"
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do square brackets mean in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692064/what-do-square-brackets-mean-in-html)

Comment: sorry no proper answer found. They say that these codes are generated by template engine. but how it works and how to manipulate things in these bracket is not clear.

Comment: "...in themes folder" ...of what? Does the software/system have a (known) name?

Comment: The proper answer depends on the templating system used.. You can't have a good explanation without telling us more details..

Comment: ok what detail do you require? i can provide

Comment: Yes these html files are located in theme folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the patterns which later will be replaced to something else by template engine. For example, [conf.site_url]/ will be replaced with http://www.example.com/ later on. You need to understand how the template engine works.